What is the best translation of Νίγερ?
BYZ  Acts 13:1

Ἦσαν δέ τινες ἐν Ἀντιοχείᾳ κατὰ τὴν οὖσαν ἐκκλησίαν προφῆται καὶ διδάσκαλοι, ὅ τε Βαρνάβας καὶ Συμεὼν ὁ καλούμενος Νίγερ, καὶ Λούκιος ὁ Κυρηναῖος, Μαναήν τε Ἡρῴδου τοῦ τετράρχου σύντροφος, καὶ Σαῦλος.

Acts 13:1 ASV

Now there were at Antioch, in the church that was there, prophets and teachers, Barnabas, and Symeon that was called Niger, and Lucius of Cyrene, and Manaen the foster-brother of Herod the tetrarch, and Saul.

What is the best translation of Νίγερ?

There are several things that can be said about the word Νίγερ (Niger):

It only occurs once in the NT in Acts 13:1
It is used as a proper name of an individual also known as "Simeon"
The word is of Latin origin meaning "black"

Indeed, we have this helpful remark from https://biblehub.com/greek/3526.htm

In the context of the early church, names often carried significant
meaning, reflecting personal characteristics, heritage, or notable
events. The use of "Niger" as a descriptor for Simeon suggests that he
may have had a darker complexion, which was notable enough to be
recorded. This highlights the diversity present in the early Christian
community, which included individuals from various ethnic and cultural
backgrounds.


Any etymological or phonological connection with the word νεκρός (nekrós)?

@Betho's - nekros means "death" in Greek; but "niger" means black in Latin.  Quite different.

The Latin word niger, meaning "black" or "dark," has an intricate etymological and cultural history. Its journey can be traced back to the Proto-Indo-European root *neḱros, which is associated with concepts of darkness, obscurity, and even death. This root gave rise to the Proto-Italic form *nigros, which then evolved into Latin niger, solidifying its meaning as "black" both in literal and figurative contexts.
Etymological Development:

Proto-Indo-European (*neḱros):

Initially connected to ideas of darkness, obscurity, and death.


Proto-Italic (*nigros):

Transitioned to describe the color black.


Latin (niger):

Literal: Physical blackness (e.g., "atramentum nigrum" = black ink).
Figurative: Abstract associations, such as "dies niger" (a dark or unlucky day).
Metaphorical Use in Scripture: In Nahum 2:10 (Latin Vulgate), the term is metaphorically linked to mourning and desolation, evoking imagery of death and darkness.



Connection to Greek Influence:
The Greek word νεκρός (nekros), meaning "dead," influenced Latin culture and language. The phonetic similarity between νεκρός and niger (or its variants like negrus) suggests a potential confluence of ideas. Enslaved individuals in Roman society, particularly Greek slaves, were often referred to as νεκρός, metaphorically implying "for death" due to their harsh treatment and social status. Over time, the term's derivatives flowed into other languages, such as:

Spanish: negro
Portuguese: negro, negrito
Italian: nero
French: noir
Romanian: negru

Cultural and Linguistic Sensitivities:
In American English, words derived from niger include:

Negro: An outdated term with a sensitive racial history.
Denigrate: From denigrare, meaning "to blacken" or criticize unfairly.

These terms highlight the complex interplay of language, culture, and social attitudes over centuries.
Theoretical Framework:

The Proto-Indo-European root *neḱros likely informed both Greek νεκρός and Latin niger through thematic overlaps of darkness and death.
Latin culture’s exposure to Greek slaves may have reinforced the metaphorical application of darkness (niger) to death (νεκρός).
This linguistic and cultural dynamic shaped the evolution of related terms across Romance languages and their reception in modern English.


Do you have a specific source for the connection between "nekros" and "nigros"? None of the sources you cited support that, nor have any others I've found. They either say "etymology unknown" or connect speculatively to a different PIE root (also "nekros" is probably a Greek, not PIE formation). Making a claim and then citing a list of books that don't support the claim is... questionable.

It's pretty common for different languages, or even a single language, to have words that sound similar but are different in meaning and have very different origins. Similarity in sound is far from conclusive evidence. In any case, as far as I can tell this is your own theory, which doesn't mean it's wrong, but it should be clearly stated as such. Making a claim and citing academic sources which don't support the claim is dishonest, your post should be clear which parts are based on the listed sources and which are your own conclusions.
